# Gitlab Badge Test Coverage is Always Unknown

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I'm trying to set up the Gitlab Test Coverage Badge, however, it is always displaying as unknown. Below is my set up:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew --build-cache -q javaToolchains
    - ./gradlew --build-cache check
    - echo "Covered 70.41% of lines matched"
  coverage: '/Covered \d+\.\d+/'
```

Badge is always displaying unknown.

Is there any steps I am missing?

I've just echo'ed a dummy value line for testing purposes. This is what I have done/confirmed so far:

- The coverage regex above does in fact match 70.41
- The job log on gitlab does output the text "Covered 70.41% of lines matched"
- That I am on the right branch when looking at the badge (Settings -> CICD -> General -> Select the test branch)

EDIT:

I think it's an issue on how Gitlab Badges retrieves this information from the branch. On the main branch, it can successfully pick up the pipeline badge, but on this feature branch, it cannot pick up either the pipeline badge or test coverage data.

Seems like the MR displays the test coverage, so it's successfully being picked up, just the data not flowing to the badge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue.

The Gitlab badge for test coverage will be scanning the latest successful pipeline logs for a specified branch (in my case a feature branch).

However, in my case, the Gitlab CI stage "test" had an `only` restriction in that it will only trigger on the master branch. So, I was previously creating a MR with this branch, and then manually triggering the pipeline. This will not classify as a pipeline running on a branch. Instead, Gitlab sees this as running on a `merge request pipeline`.

The solution to this was to either remove the restriction that the CI stage will only run on the master branch by removing that line of code within Gitlab CI. Or in my case, whitelisting the name of the feature branch to the list in the only field. Now, when you push a new change to the branch, the pipeline should automatically trigger (even without a MR open) and if you have the test coverage total amount printed out in the logs, along with the relevant regex, then the data should be able to be caught by the Gitlab Badge.